# How to re-render a component after clicking a bootstrap modal button in React.js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

So I want to delete a user from my database, for just to confirm a user's action, I'm showing a warning on modal, If user will click the Delete button on modal, the delete function will be called. All works good except one thing, after deletion, my component is not re-rendering, for that purpose I need to use window.location.reload() which causes the whole page reload, to show the updated list of the users, but I don't want a full page reload, just want that specific component to be updated.

Here's the button which is calling the modal and updating value in a use state hook

```
<i
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#exampleModal"
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => setDelUser(val.userEmail)}
                        className="fas fa-trash-alt"
                      ></i>
```

Here's the button on the modal which is dismissing the modal and calling the delete function

```
<button
                  type="submit"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  onClick={handleDelete}
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
```

And here's the delete function

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
if (delUser === admin) {
  toast.error("Cannot delete the default admin!");
  return;
} else {
  try {
    const result = await Http.post(`${Config.apiUrl}/users/delete`, {
      email: delUser,
    });
    setDelUser("");
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404) {
      toast.error(ex.response.data);
    }
  }
}
```

};

Comment: please provide your code with https://codesandbox.io/ so that we can give you the solution faster

Comment: Add jsx part of your code

Comment: Consider calling get request after your post request to refresh a list of users. In that way updated list of users will be shown.

Comment: you can update the table data which is stored in the state (assume so). Simple remove the particular item from the list after the confirmation. This way you won't need to call any API and data will also be updated

Comment: @TrySetyoUtomo okay here's the code https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-rumple-8sgl1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma yes the one you are talking about is optimistic approach, i'll follow that soon, but right now, i want to know what's wrong with this code... if you can check the link i mentioned in the comments of my code on codesandbox.io

Comment: Just checked the code you have posted. The basic rule of react says it will rerender the component when state changes its value. In your case after the delete confirmation ajax call you are calling the code setDelUser(""); which is not changing the initial value of this state. Initially this value was blank and after the ajax call this value is still blank hence your component is not rerendering. Remove the window.load and change the value of state to something else.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma if you see the first piece of code above, there's a line "onClick={() => setDelUser(val.userEmail)}".... here i'm changing the state of the delUser, and in the deletion i just made it empty so that the state change and re render... but i tried to change that setDelUser('') to setDelUser('Deleted!').... but it's still not working bro

Comment: ok, so the workflow is, user will click the delete icon in table and on confirmation the page will re-render. I have tried to modify your code by commenting the ajax call and added some dummy data just to show it is working fine. There must be issue in your ajax call. run this sandbox and observer the console panel. I can suggest, check if your API is receiving the post requests else the page will not re-render as you are using await in the api call, the code execution will wait until the response is received. https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-volhard-00qyi?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly thanks for give me your sandbox, I was trying to modify your code, unfortunately I can't check your data cause your API data come from `localhost`, but i modified the data become `static` json first,

I modified your code [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-chatterjee-iw57k?file=/src/App.js),I recomend you to use Modal React instead of Modal pure html,  then after `selected data` has removed by API, I use`lodash` to remove the `selected data` from all data, then data has been removed without refresh.